# convert checked checkboxs to selected options and add to given select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my search results output is `<input type="checkbox" name="participants" id="participants" value="<?php echo $id ?>"><p style="display: initial;"><?php echo $fullname."(center name:$center)" ?></p>`

and my output lookslike [image]

and my output code looks like

```
<div class="row" id="searchstudents">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participants" id="participants" value="1"><p style="display: initial;">karthik gone(center name:srnagar)</p>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participants" id="participants" value="2"><p style="display: initial;">laxmi(center name:vvnagar)</p>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participants" id="participants" value="4"><p style="display: initial;">ram(center name:vvnagar)</p>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participants" id="participants" value="5"><p style="display: initial;">srikanth(center name:srnagar)</p>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participants" id="participants" value="6"><p style="display: initial;">narayana(center name:vvnagar)</p>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participants" id="participants" value="9"><p style="display: initial;">vivek(center name:vvnagar)</p>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participants" id="participants" value="10"><p style="display: initial;">ghtfr(center name:vvnagar)</p>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participants" id="participants" value="11"><p style="display: initial;">karthik g(center name:vvnagar)</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

here what im doing is after multiple checkboxs checked and click "add to participants" button add this participanrts to dropdown list means convert to option and add to select list.

plase help me what to do?

Comment: First of, you should not have multiple elements with the same id, ids should always be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is what you were asking for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("input[type=button]").click(function() {
    $('input:checked').each(function() {
      var newOption = new Option($(this).parent().find("p").html(),$(this).val() , true, true);
      $('select').append(newOption);
    })
  });
});
```

@edit fixed fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/wp2acsjn/5/

Comment: Thanks for example but after open the link and i trid click button but nothing happed

Comment: Try now, i fixed a fiddle cause it was saved wrongly. Check some checkboxes and click the button.

Comment: thanks its worked fine. but i have other radio button  which selected so when i tried  $('input:checked').each(function() its adding other checked radio into select option

Comment: So change `$('input:checked')` to `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')` so only checked checkboxes will be added to the select.

Answer (score 0):

when a checkbox is checked you can create and append an `option` element to a `select` element that contains the text in the `p` tag:

```js
document.getElementById('searchstudents').addEventListener('change', addToSelectList);
const selectElement = document.getElementById('mySelect');
function addToSelectList() {
    let selected = event.target;
    
    if(!selected.checked) {
     let index = document.getElementById(`option${selected.value}`).index;
     selectElement.remove(index);
      return;
    }
    
    let text = selected.nextElementSibling.textContent;
    let option = document.createElement('OPTION');
    option.textContent = text;
    option.id = 'option' + selected.value;
    selectElement.appendChild(option);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#mySelect {
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="searchstudents">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participants" class="participants" value="1"><p style="display: initial;">karthik gone(center name:srnagar)</p>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participants" class="participants" value="2"><p style="display: initial;">laxmi(center name:vvnagar)</p>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participants" class="participants" value="3"><p style="display: initial;">ram(center name:vvnagar)</p>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participants" class="participants" value="4"><p style="display: initial;">srikanth(center name:srnagar)</p>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participants" class="participants" value="5"><p style="display: initial;">narayana(center name:vvnagar)</p>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participants" class="participants" value="6"><p style="display: initial;">vivek(center name:vvnagar)</p>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participants" class="participants" value="7"><p style="display: initial;">ghtfr(center name:vvnagar)</p>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="participants" class="participants" value="8"><p style="display: initial;">karthik g(center name:vvnagar)</p>
        </div>
</div>
<br>
<select id="mySelect">
</select>
```